# Error: Expected Literal, got 'CASE'

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have the following query which I need to modify to work with symfony2.

```
SELECT someColumn, COUNT(*) AS n, 
SUM(IF(STATUS = 20,1,0)) AS sent 
FROM someTable 
WHERE ID = :id;
```

What I have done till now:

```
$query = ("SELECT myEntity.someField AS someColumn,
            SUM(CASE WHEN myEntity.status = '20' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sent
            FROM AppRoot\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity myEntity
            WHERE myEntity.id = :id
            ");
```

But I get the dreaded error:

```
Error: Expected Literal, got 'CASE'
```

Comment: @jarlh I will need it later on but currently my main issue is this error which doesn't make sense and how to translate COUNT(*) from sql to dql.

Comment: have you tried to remove the `,` at the end of the following line: `SUM(CASE WHEN myEntity.status = '20' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sent,` (not sure it'll solve your issue but you shouldn't have a comma before the `FROM`)

Comment: @Snroki Yes, it was a typo. I have not copied the whole code but rather the semplified version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you call it from an EntityRepository, you can instance a \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder like this:

```
$em = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
```

Next, you can build the query using:

```
$qb->select(array(
    'myEntity.someField as someColumn',
    'count(myEntity) as n',
    'SUM(CASE WHEN myEntity.status = :status then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sent',
    ... // add all the columns you need
  ))
  ->from('AppRoot\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity','MyEntity')
  ->where( $qb->expr()->eq('myEntity.id', ':id') )
  ->setParameters(array(
      'status'=>'20',
      'id' => $theEntityId
  ));
```

And finally you can retrieve your result like this:

```
$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

or if you prefer a plain old-style array:

```
$qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

This should work and you may inspect the generated queries with:

```
$qb->getQuery()->getDQL(); // get the Doctrine Query Language query
$qb->getQuery()->getSQL(); // get the SQL generated query
```

Comment: I still get "Error: Expected Literal, got 'CASE'

Comment: I suspect that perhaps doctrine doesn't recognize the operator CASE, although it should be, being version 2.1.6

Comment: Just to understand:Do you get the same error if you take SUM off?

Comment: I get a similar error: "Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | StateFieldPathExpression | AggregateExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | ScalarExpression, got 'CASE' "

Comment: `Error: Expected IdentificationVariable` This error Comes when columns names were not matched.

Comment: i am also getting the same issue "Error: Expected Literal, got 'CASE' i found the solution we have to use the DoctrineExtension .Did you Got the Solutions .?